# Is there an equivalent (or faster) version of numpy.binCount in R for summing values based on multiple bins?

Tags: python, r, algorithm, performance, numpy

I have an algorithm which requires a changing vector 'wgts' of N numbers to be summed according to the categories in an M-by-N matrix of integers 'bins'. For example, if the initial values of 'wgts' are [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.6] and B is [[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1], [2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]], the result would be [[(0.2 + 0.7), (0.4 + 0.6), (0.3 + 0.1)], [(0.7 + 0.6), (0.2 + 0.4), (0.3 + 0.1)]

I need to repeat that process with a fixed category matrix 'bins', and changing vector 'wgts'. As M and N become large, this process, takes a lot of time. I have found that the python package numpy has a useful and fast function bincount for this. I would like to use R, as the rest of my process is in R, but so far I'm not able to right my algorithm in R as fast as in Python

The approach in R that seems to work the fastest so far is to save separate, logical M-by-N matrices, one for each category. However, it is still takes about twice as long as my Python script, and I assume it requires more memory, though I'm not sure how to measure that part. Below are my Python and R scripts with their processing times.

```
# R First attempt, "straightforward"
smplSize <- 1000000
binTypes <- 100
nIter <- 20

set.seed(1)
bins <- matrix(floor(runif(smplSize * binTypes, min=0, max=5)), 
                  nrow = smplSize)
wgts <- runif(smplSize)

tic <- Sys.time()
for (i in (1:nIter)) {

  res <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=binTypes)
  for (j in 0:4) {
    res[j+1,] <- colSums(wgts * (bins == j))
  }

  # Some process that modifies wgts based on res
}
toc <- Sys.time()
toc - tic # 117 seconds
```

```
# Second attempt, storing category locations in separate mask matrices
tic <- Sys.time()
# Store 5 matrices identifying locations of the integers 0 - 4
binMask <- list()
for (i in 0:4) {
  binMask[[i+1]] <- bins == i
}

for (i in (1:nIter)) {
  res <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=binTypes)
  for (j in 0:4) {
    res[j+1,] <- colSums(wgts * binMask[[j + 1]])
  }

  # Some process that modifies wgts based on res
}
toc <- Sys.time()
toc - tic # 72 seconds

print(object.size(binMask), units = "Gb") # 1.9 Gb
```

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit
import sys

smplSize = 1000000
nBins = 100
nIter = 20
wgts = np.random.random_sample(smplSize)
bins = np.random.randint(0, 5, (smplSize, nBins))

tic=timeit.default_timer()
res = np.bincount(bins, wgts)
toc=timeit.default_timer()
toc - tic

tic=timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(nIter):
    res = np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, 0, bins, wgts)
toc=timeit.default_timer()
toc - tic # 39 seconds

sys.getsizeof(bins)/(1024 ** 2) # 381 Mb
```

I am running R 3.4.4 and Python 3.6.1 on a 64-bit Windows desktop, Intel Xeon CPU E5-2680, 96GB RAM.

I've looked into whether or not Python is somehow caching calculations, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I have toyed a bit with data.table 'group' calculations, but I haven't come up with a good way to handle multiple column to group by.

In R, to check for calculation accuracy, the value of res[1, 1] is 99967.64

Comment: You can take a look at the "parallel" package.  Replace the for loops with `parSapply`

Comment: Thank @Dave2e for the suggestion. I actually can't run the out for loop (1:nIter) because the vector wgts changes depending on the previous loop's calculation. Also, this is part of a larger process that is running in parallel, and I am running low on CPU resources.

Comment: You have some problems with indices in your code. In R rows (and vectors) start from 1...

Comment: Thanks @minem. I must have been switching to quickly between R and Python. I've fixed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe with data.table, but we need to change the structure of bins before:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(bins = as.integer(bins), # integer for reduced size
                    row = rep(1:nrow(bins), ncol(bins)),
                    col = rep(1:ncol(bins), each = nrow(bins)))
```

now the rest:

```
dt[, wg := wgts[row]] # add wgts for each corresponding row to data.table
rez <- dt[, .(wg_sum = sum(wg)), by = .(col, bins)] # sum by "cols" & bins
rez # your results, only in different structure
# (i would suggest keeping this, if possible)

# if needed can cast to similar structure as your original results:
rezt <- dcast(rez, bins ~ col, value.var = 'wg_sum')
```

but maybe this doesn't suet your needs as you mention that you are doing also other things in loop...

timing only the sum for 20 times:

```
tic <- Sys.time()
for (i in (1:nIter)) {
  rez <- dt[, .(wg_sum = sum(wg)), by = .(col, bins)]
}
toc <- Sys.time()
toc - tic # 48.8 45.9 45.9 38.9
```

not as fast as in python, but as we are summing 100e6 elements by 100x5 groups makes sense.

```
# maybe if we split the huge dt before by bins in list:
dtl <- split(dt, by = 'bins')
tic <- Sys.time()
for (i in (1:nIter)) {
  r <- lapply(dtl, function(x) x[, sum(wg), col])
}
toc <- Sys.time()
toc - tic # 18.062
```

but in this case you need to treat the results differently after summing...

Comment: This is excellent! Brings my performance much closer to python's. I just needed to use the wgts vector indexed by the column 'row' in dtl, since, the values of wgts will change. Here's what I ended up using: `tic <- Sys.time()
dtl <- split(dt, by = 'bins', sorted = TRUE)`

`for (i in (1:nIter)) {
  r <- sapply(dtl, function(x) x[, sum(wgts[row]), col][, V1])
}
toc <- Sys.time()
toc - tic # 42.4 secs`